# Azure table Storage : How to implement Pagination?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to implement pagination in Spring boot web application. I am using Azure table storage Java API(version 4.3.0) to store data.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599511/add-pagination-mvc-and-azure-table-storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this. You can find full code [here](https://github.com/sunilsoni/spring-cloud-microservices/blob/master/po-service/src/main/java/com/jci/po/repo/PoRepoImpl.java#L207)