# azure table storage pagination for request 10 items each time

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-storage

Basically I am trying to get pagination working when requesting entities of azure table storage. i.e. Press next button gets the next 10 entities & Press previous button gets the previous 10 entities. A relatively close example [Gaurav Mantri's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599511/add-pagination-mvc-and-azure-table-storage). But my question is how do I get the [*nextPartitionKey*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) and [*nextRowKey*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) from a HTML button attribute and store in to a array/list in order to keep track of current page so I can get the next/previous items?Code example would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

This is something I have right now which gets a range of data based on pageNumber request

```cs
private async Task<List<UserInfo>> queryPage(CloudTable peopleTable, string item, int pageNumber)
    {
        // Construct the query operation for all customer entities 
        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, item));

        // Print the fields for each customer.
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        //TodoItem data = new TodoItem();
        List<UserInfo> data = new List<UserInfo>();

        do
        {
            TableQuerySegment<CustomerEntity> resultSegment = await peopleTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
            token = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;

            foreach (CustomerEntity entity in resultSegment.Results)
            {

                data.Add(new UserInfo
                {
                    // add data
                });

            }
        } while (token != null);

        //get a subset of all entity
        List<UserInfo> sublist = data.GetRange(0, pageNumber);



        return sublist;
    }
```

Comment: Some pointers to get you started:

 1. Since it is a web application (thus stateless), I recommend that you keep the continuation token array on the client side.
 2. Your `queryPage` method should accept continuation token as input parameter and return the continuation token back to the client along with the data.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for your help! Just wondering how do I return together with the continuation token if my _queryPage_ is returning a list of items from the table?

Comment: `Tuple` to the rescue :). Or you can create a custom class that has two properties: 1) List of entities and 2) Continuation token.

Comment: @GauravMantri Problem solved! Thanks :)  BTW it's really strange that there is no row count feature in Azure Table Storage..

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind posting your solution as an answer here. It might help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solved the problem under Gaurav's help.
Here is the code, not perfect but works.

```cs
private async Task<List<UserInfo>> queryPage(CloudTable peopleTable, string item, string NextPartitionKey , string NextRowKey, int itemNumber)
    {
        // Construct the query operation for all customer entities 
        TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, item)).Take(itemNumber);


        // Print the fields for each customer.
        List<UserInfo> data = new List<UserInfo>();

        Tabletoken.NextPartitionKey = NextPartitionKey;
        Tabletoken.NextRowKey = NextRowKey;
        TableQuerySegment<CustomerEntity> resultSegment = await peopleTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, Tabletoken);
        Tabletoken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;


        foreach (CustomerEntity entity in resultSegment.Results)
        {

            data.Add(new UserInfo
            {
                //add data
            });

        }

        return data;
    }

    private TableContinuationToken Tabletoken = new TableContinuationToken();
```

and declare it use a tuple.

```cs
 Tuple<List<UserInfo>, string, string > tuple =
                new Tuple<List<UserInfo>, string, string>(data, Tabletoken.NextPartitionKey, Tabletoken.NextRowKey);
```