# Azure table storage php pagination not working

Tags: php, azure, pagination

I am new to azure table storage and I was building a table with pagination links with data from azure table storage with php. You can check for example  [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-tables-php-pagination-query/).All works fine until 1000 records but when I go to 1010 records it returns this error:-

> Fail: Code: 400 Value: Bad Request details (if any):
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"One
>   of the request inputs is not valid.

So this code in example's `queryPaginationEntitiesSample function {$options->setTop($numPerPage * ($page-1));}` is causing this error. Can someone help me with this issue?

```
function queryPaginationEntitiesSample($tableClient,$tableName,$numPerPage,$page,$filter) { 
    try { 
        $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions(); 
        $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter)); 
        if($page==1){ 
            $options->setTop($numPerPage);
            $options->setSelectFields(array('PartitionKey','RowKey','Timestamp'));  
            $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($tableName, $options); 
            $entities = $result->getEntities(); 
        } else{ 

             //skip $numPerPage * ($page-1) records 
            $options->setTop($numPerPage * ($page-1)); 
            $options->setSelectFields(array('PartitionKey','RowKey','Timestamp')); 
            $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($tableName, $options); 
            $nRowKey = $result->getNextRowKey(); 
            $nPartitionKey = $result->getNextPartitionKey(); 
            $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions(); 
            $options->setFilter(Filter::applyQueryString($filter)); 
            $options->setTop($numPerPage); 
            $options->setNextRowKey($nRowKey); 
            $options->setNextPartitionKey($nPartitionKey);  
            $result = $tableClient->queryEntities($tableName, $options); 
            $entities = $result->getEntities(); 
        }
        return $entities; 
    }catch(ServiceException $e){ 
        $code = $e->getCode(); 
        $error_message = $e->getMessage(); 
        echo $code.": ".$error_message.PHP_EOL; 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the value set for `$numPerPage`?

Comment: $numPerPage is set to 10

Comment: and also I m using  JasonGrimes\Paginator for pagination

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you’re using.

Comment: I have added full pagination function now

Comment: Please tell me is it possible to show pagination after 1000 records?, as when it sets Top to 1010 records it breaks and gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum entities that can be fetched in a single request to table service is `1000`. Since you're asking the table service to return `1010` entities, you're getting this error.

I think you would need to change your logic somehow (sorry, I am not that versed with PHP, hence can't provide the code). But essentially you would need to return the continuation tokens (next PartitionKey and next RowKey) along with entities and pass these values to `queryPaginationEntitiesSample` method and use them.

Please see [azure table storage pagination for request 10 items each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621281/azure-table-storage-pagination-for-request-10-items-each-time?noredirect=1&lq=1) as a reference (the solution is in .Net).

Comment: Is there a way to skip records and get next ones ?

Comment: I have set per page records to 10 so all works fine till page 101 and setTop is set to 1000 at this time, but when I request for page 102 setTop gets set to 1010 and the error comes, so please give me some idea, how I can set setTop to 1000 after page 101?. I am also able to get next partition key and next row keys but it brokes when comes to page 102

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is you're trying to modify the value of `$top` in each iteration, which *isn't* the same thing as `SKIP`.

From the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

> `$top`    Returns only the top n tables or entities from the set.

Basically you need to get the *continuation token* and provide the *same* filters and `$top` each time.

What you're currently doing is effectively increasing the amount of results you want each 'page' of data. For example, with a `$top` of 10:

```
Page 1: 10 entries retrieved. 10 total entries retrieved.
Page 2: 10 entries retrieved. 20 total entries retrieved.
Page 3: 20 entries retrieved. 40 total entries retrieved.
Page 4: 30 entries retrieved. 70 total entries retrieved.
...
Page 99: 990 entries retrieved. 49510 total entries retrieved.
Page 101: 1000 entries retrieved. 50510 total entries retrieved.
Page 102: 1010 entries attempted. <-- Not allowed by design.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a sample code to get all rows:

```
$entities = ListAzureTable("mytable", "(PartitionKey eq 'XXXX')");

function ListAzureTable($table, $stringFilter)
{
    global $tableRestProxy;
    
    $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
    $filter  = new QueryStringFilter($stringFilter);
    $options->setFilter($filter);
    $result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities($table, $options);
    $entities = $result->getEntities();
    $nextPK = $result->getNextPartitionKey();
    $nextRK = $result->getNextRowKey();
    
    while ($nextPK != null && $nextPK != "")
    {
        $options = new QueryEntitiesOptions();
        $options->setFilter($filter);
        $options->setNextPartitionKey($nextPK);
        $options->setNextRowKey($nextRK);
        $result = $tableRestProxy->queryEntities($table, $options);
        $nextPK=$result->getNextPartitionKey();
        $nextRK=$result->getNextRowKey();
        $newentities=$result->getEntities();
        
        $entities=array_merge($newentities, $entities);
    }
    
    return $entities;
}
```